# how to stop vim moving javascript object keys to column 0

Tags: javascript, vim, syntax

When typing javascript object literals, such as:

```
foo = {
    bar: baz
};
```

vim thinks "bar:" is a C-style label and moves it to column 0.

How do I stop this?

Comment: I think it's to do with the way `:` is used for switches. It dedents it, not moves it to column 0. It doesn't show up for simple structures but only for more complex ones, I've found (and sometimes it just doesn't seem to happen... like now when I try to reproduce it!). Whatever it is, though, I've been annoyed by it as well and just learned to live with it... hope someone has an answer for it :-)

Comment: This has always annoyed me.  Maddeningly the [cinoptions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#cinoptions-values) setting looks like it will do what we want but it's just aware enough of C-like syntax to only obey `cino=:1s` if it really is a case label in a switch statement, sadly, not for JS object literals...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `:set cinkeys-=:`.

Label indentation cannot be controlled by `cinoptions`. To quote from `:help indent`

Vim puts a line in column 1 if:

> - It starts with '#' (preprocessor directives), if 'cinkeys' contains '#'.
> - **It starts with a label (a keyword followed by ':', other than "case" and
>      "default").**
> - Any combination of indentations causes the line to have less than 0
>     indentation.

(Emphasis mine)

However, `cinkeys` specifies which keys trigger reindenting in insert mode. By removing `:` from `cinkeys`, vim will no longer reindent on inserting `:`.

But be aware that manual re-indenting via `=` *will* still break your layout.